# Python, no module named stringprep

Tags: python, pip, tensorflow

Написал некоторый код с помощью python и tensorflow, и получил ошибку

```
  ImportError: No module named 'stringprep'
```

которая возникает в коде Tensorflow, в интернете не нашел каким методом можно подключить модуль который не установлен, возможно кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой.

Python v3.5
Tensorflow v1.13.1

Comment: ` каким методом можно подключить модуль который не установлен` а если сделать так `pip install stringprep`?

Comment: @gil9red неработает - Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement stringprep (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for stringprep

Comment: Оказывается stringprep есть из коробки: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stringprep.html Другой вопрос, почему нет у вас...

Comment: @ПетроЧайківський, как вы устанавливали Tensorflow? Я бы попробовал установить Tensorflow используя “conda” из дистрибутива Anaconda

Comment: @MaxU с помощью  docker, https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker

Comment: @gil9red мне интересно что делать если его нет

Comment: @ПетроЧайківський, можете привести в вопросе “error traceback” целиком?